# encoding problem with rails and sql server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I have a Rails app hooked up to a SQL server database using the "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter" gem. Some of the tables contain Unicode characters, which display fine if I look at them using the Microsoft SQL Server tool, but which don't get displayed correctly on the site itself (they get replaced with the rotated box-with-question mark).

If I open up a console and access the field, I see something like "\xA9" for the copyright symbol (which I believe is an incorrect Unicode encoding).

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to SQL Server, but make sure your database.yml file contains `encoding: utf8` in each environment section.

Comment: Yep, I'm using that, but I still have the problem.